# Find if allocation is trivially resizable?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, realloc

`realloc` may simply update bookkeeping info here and there to increase your allocation size, or it may actually `malloc` a new one and `memcpy` the previous allocation (or may fail).

I want to be able to query the memory manager if an allocation is *trivially resizable* (either because it reserved more than I `malloc`d or because it was able coalesce adjacent blocks , etc...) and if yes, then I'll ask it to go ahead and do so, else I'd want to `malloc` and `memcpy` an arbitrary subset of the original allocation in an arbitrary order myself.

Other StackOverflow answers seem to do one of these four :

- Suggest `realloc` anyways. This *can* be quite inefficient for large quantities of data, where the double-copy can have serious effect. Usually, it is the fastest portable route.
- Suggest manual `malloc` + `memcpy` + `free`. This is worse, because now instead of *some* double copying when allocation may not be resized, *everything* is double copied every time the allocation fills up. Performs terribly.
- Suggest a platform specific extension. This is not practical, as my code, like a lot of C code, requires portability.
- Suggest it's impossible. C already assumes the presence of a memory manager with ability to either resize allocations in place *or* create a new one. So, why can't I have one more level of control on it? We can have aligned malloc; why not this ?

*NOTE* : This question is posted under both C and C++ tags because solutions from either language are acceptable and relevant.

**EDIT 1:**

In the words of FB vector :

> But wait, there's more. Many memory allocators do not support in- place reallocation, although most of them could. This comes from the now notorious design of realloc() to opaquely perform either in-place reallocation or an allocate-memcpy-deallocate cycle. Such lack of control subsequently forced all clib-based allocator designs to avoid in-place reallocation, and that includes C++'s new and std::allocator. This is a major loss of efficiency because an in-place reallocation, being very cheap, may mean a much less aggressive growth strategy. In turn that means less slack memory and faster reallocations.

See [this](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/main/folly/docs/FBVector.md).

Comment: There is no standard or portable way to do this. That's what "impossible" probably refers to in this case. Not that it is not technically possible to implement. Just that the C spec does not specify that and hence it's not possible without non-standard extensions.

Comment: @kaylum Is WG14 open to such a suggestion ? Or is libc not their current focus ?

Comment: Your list seems to be correct and exhaustive. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @eerorika "is there a way to do this that I have not come across in my search ?"

Comment: Suggest to write your own allocator, if you need custom semantics. How much memory are you allocating? I can't imagine a copy of like big block of memory taking that long. I see https://www.quora.com/How-long-would-it-take-to-load-a-1GB-file-into-RAM-if-the-speed-of-the-drive-the-file-was-stored-on-didnt-matter it would take 0.15 seconds on my pc to copy 1GB, that's not that much, you don't realloc that often.

Comment: For the non-trivially reallocatable case, why would you prefer to `malloc` and `memcpy` manually?  Why not just let `realloc` do it for you?  And what do you mean by "double copying"?  There should be only one copy being performed.  Also, although copying can be expensive and terrible, most people don't care because it's usually amortized by growing the buffer exponentially.

Comment: @KamilCuk this seems a bit overkill.

Comment: @jamesdlin Double copying may occur because I may not want the old data to be copied *as-is* (think inserting a dynamic array or vector into another , where the destination is full).

Comment: @NeedHelp so `std::vector`?

Comment: Jemalloc includes this functionality, just use it. It is more portable than most people will ever need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Suggest realloc anyways. This can be quite inefficient for large quantities of data, where the double-copy can have serious effect.

Due to reasons *why* realloc can sometimes avoid copying and allocation, this is an irrelevant point because in practical implementations, that condition doesn't exist with large quantities of data. If you know that the allocation is large, then it's fairly safe to assume that realloc will have to copy and allocate. Hence, you can make the choice without having to make the "impossible" check.

If reallocation is optional and you cannot afford the copy, then unconditionally choose the option to not reallocate. If reallocation isn't optional, then whether realloc would copy and allocate or not doesn't have an effect on what you have to do.

> Suggest a platform specific extension. This is not practical, as my code, like a lot of C code, requires portability.

This is the only way to achieve what you're asking for because there is no standard way to query whether realloc will copy and allocate.

However, keep in mind that it is possible to port such code by conditionally disabling this feature using pre-defined macros.

> Suggest it's impossible.

This is true if you choose to rely on standard C++.

> is there a way to do this that I have not come across in my search ?

No, the list is exhaustive.

Comment: I have taken this advice and simply used `realloc`, as I am cannot `#ifdef` away every platform and not will be making my own allocator / requiring one as a dependancy.

Answer (score 2):

The *standard* memory interface is well documented. If you want some feature that isn't part of that interface, your solution is going to be custom, third party, or platform-specific.

> - Suggest it's impossible. C already assumes the presence of a memory manager with ability to either resize allocations in place or create a new one. So, why can't I have one more level of control on it?

Because it isn't part of the standard interface. The fact that it *could* have been made part of the standard interface does not mean that is *is* part of the standard interface.

> ... We can have aligned malloc; why not this ?

If you want it to be in the standard, propose a change to the working group. It's not going to arrive quickly.

If you want something to work *now*, you need to write your own allocator or find a third-party one that meets your requirements.

Note that

> - Suggest a platform specific extension. This is not practical, as my code, like a lot of C code, requires portability.

isn't a real problem (or at least, is one that people often cope with just fine). You may have to write a different implementation for each platform you want to support (and fall back on `realloc` where nothing better is available), but this isn't uncommon for cross-platform code.

Comment: "*If you want it to be in the standard, propose a change to the working group*". How receptive is the C committee to such libc additions ? AFAIK the only changes to libc have been format specifiers, atomics & threads (with C++), new macros, and some bounds checking functions. Most changes have been optional, except feature test macros that confirm their absence.

Comment: I probably wouldn't even try until I'd written an interface I was happy was consistent with the rest of the library, written up a proposal consistent with other similar proposals, and tested a sample implementation in glibc or similar. You could start by contacting your local participating national body, though. [Contacts](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/contacts#liaisons)

Comment: It appears my nation does not participate. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score -2):

I suppose that what you wanna get is the size of spare space following your malloc'ed memory block. It is possible, memory manager reserves a header before each block, you can get information you want from the block header, but obviously it is not portable due to different implementation of various memory manager.
I think a better way is to use a memory pool to manage heap memory yourself, it will be more efficient and portable.

Comment: No, resisability of a block depends on various factors, all I want to know is if the block can be resized to some size at runtime. This can be done portably, because an implementation that does something odd can legally `void *resize(void *p) { return NULL; }`.

Comment: Just call realloc(). realloc() will resize the block and return the same pointer you passed in if there is enough spare space after the block, otherwise it will find a new place for the block and then it will return a new pointer.